# Getting result from entered date between two columns

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

I need help with validation in order reservation. I have table reservation for items and I need get all items between specific dates.

I using timestamp because I need get all orders with minute precision.

*tbl_reservation*

```
orderid | itemid | quantity | from | to

Order 1: from 16-12-2018 00:00 to 23-12-2018 23:59

Order 2: from 21-12-2018 20:00 to 24-12-2018 20:01
```

#### My query:

```
SELECT itemid,
       SUM(quantity) AS sum
FROM tbl_order_reservation
WHERE ( "orderid" <> '18112021270001hcr1' ) AND ( "itemid" IN (
     '18111318230001hlk1'
) ) AND (
     "from" >= '2018-11-21 20:00:00' 
AND "to" <= '2018-11-24 20:01:00'  OR "from" BETWEEN '2018-11-21 20:00:00'
     AND '2018-11-24 20:01:00' OR
  "to" BETWEEN '2018-11-21 20:00:00' AND '2018-11-24 20:01:00'
)
GROUP BY "itemid"
```

#### What I need:

Now if I want change date or add new item to order and I need validate if is available quantity in reservation order. But my query missing one condition like **mydate** between **from** and **to** columns. It's possible?

So I need query where I know only from and to but, if is between two dates from table, I don't know write condition for this.

#### Example:

query

```
from 17-12-2018 14:00 to 17-12-2018 17:00
```

and this query must result order 1 so order where is `date from 16-12-2018 00:00 to 23-12-2018 23:59`

It's possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you want `OVERLAPS`

```
SELECT * FROM  tbl_reservation
        WHERE OVERLAPS('17-12-2018 14:00'::TIMESTAMP, 
                       '17-12-2018 17:00'::TIMESTAMP, 
                      "from", "to") ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f6b205930acb602a88680f235d8451c3)

Comment: Absolutely! You're amazing. Thanks